# JAMA - How to combine vectors into a single matrix

Tags: matrix, vector, jama

I have a total of 4 column vectors which look like this:

```
m1:       m2:        m3:      m4:

0.26      -0.25      0.04     0.43
-0.20     -0.12      0.50     0.47
-0.27      0.79     -0.37     0.29
-0.06     -0.45     -0.71     0.44
-0.23      0.13      0.31     0.52
 0.87      0.29      0.02     0.23
```

I want to combine these 4 column vectors and put them in a single 6x4 matrix. How do I achieve this in JAMA? All four column matrices are of Matrix type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer myself. Basically, we use a variant of the `setMatrix()` method that has the following signature:

```
setMatrix(int[] r, int j0, int j1, Matrix X)
where,
r = array of row indices
j0 = initial column index
j1 = final column index
X = matrix you want to insert i.e. m1/m2/m3/m4 in my case
```

To set m1 in the first column of my matrix (say) meu, I can code it as follows:

```
int[] r = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // since each of m1, m2, m3 and m4 have 6 rows
meu.setMatrix(r, 0, 0, m1); //sets submatrix m1 to 1st column (hence j0=j1=0)
```

To set m2 in the second column of my meu, I do:

```
meu.setMatrix(r, 1, 1, m2); //sets submatrix m2 to 2nd column
```

.... and similarly for the rest as well.